# How to add static data columns in dataTable existing columns

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Have requirement like API gives few columns of data and I need to add some static data columns. Is there any way to add few columns dynamically passing below like `{ data: this.test1 },{ data: this.test2 }`. I tried to add two columns but unable to fetch the data, getting blank cells.

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   public test1 =123;
   public test2 =234;
```

Initialization:

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: "full_numbers",
  pageLength: 10,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  processing: true,
  destroy: true,
  scrollY:'50vh',
  columns: [
    { title: '<input type="checkbox" />' },
    { data: "index" },
    { data: "firstname" },
    { data: "lastname" },
    { data: this.test1 },
    { data: this.test2 }
  ],
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-3c2rum?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `data` to null and then use the [`defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) option.

Hard-coded in the column definition:

```
{ title: "Hard-Coded Data", data: null, defaultContent: "foo" }
```

Similar, but using a JavaScript variable - for example, `var bar = 'baz';`:

```
{ title: "Hard-Coded Data", data: null, defaultContent: bar }
```